# LWC use querySelectorAll to get all ids associated with checked checkboxes in the view, and update the Database

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, css

My goal is onclick of any checkbox here, get the data-id of all checked activities. I've tried several things, but new to LWC and fairly new to selectors.

Currently, when I click any checkbox, the last 4 lines in the Console here print. In my reading, it seems that SecureNodeList may not be traversable.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

---

```
<template>
  <lightning-card>
  <h3 slot="title">
      <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:connected_apps" size="small"></lightning-icon>
      Activities
  </h3>
  <div class="slds-m-left_medium slds-m-right_medium slds-text-medium">
    Remember to click Save after checking off activities. Once all Mandated Activities 
    have been checked off, you may Submit to your manager.
  </div>

  <div slot="footer">
    <!-- Neutral variant (default) -->
    <lightning-button label="Save" onchange={selectAllCheckedOffActivities} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
    <!-- Neutral variant (default) -->
    <lightning-button label="Submit" title="Non-primary action" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
  </div>


    <div class="slds-m-left_medium slds-m-top_medium slds-m-bottom_medium">
      <div class="slds-text-heading_medium">Mandated Activities</div>
      <template for:each={mandatedActivities} for:item="activity">
          <span key={activity.id}>
            <div class="slds-col">
                <lightning-input type="checkbox" data-id={activity.id} label={activity.title} checked={activity.isChecked}></lightning-input>
            </div>
          </span>
      </template>
      <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-m-top_medium">If Appropriate</div>
      <template for:each={ifAppropriateActivities} for:item="activity">
        <span key={activity.id}>
          <div class="slds-col">
              <lightning-input type="checkbox" data-id={activity.id} label={activity.title} checked={activity.isChecked}></lightning-input>
          </div>
        </span>
      </template>
      <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-m-top_medium">Optional Activities</div>
      <template for:each={optionalActivities} for:item="activity">
        <span key={activity.id}>
          <div class="slds-col">
              <lightning-input type="checkbox" data-id={activity.id} label={activity.title} checked={activity.isChecked}></lightning-input>
          </div>
        </span>
      </template>
    </div>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

---

```
import {LightningElement, wire, track} from 'lwc';
import {CurrentPageReference} from 'lightning/navigation';
import getEventActivityWrappers from '@salesforce/apex/EventActivities_Ctrl.getEventActivityWrappers';
import updateEventActivityCheckboxTracker from '@salesforce/apex/EventActivities_Ctrl.updateEventActivityCheckboxTracker';

export default class EventActivityChecklist extends LightningElement {

  @track currentPageReference = null;
  @track siteSurveyId = '';
  @track activityIdsForTracker = 'a1e1k00000Fvv6TAAR,a1e1k00000Fvv6UAAR,a1e1k00000Fvv6dAAB';

  @track activities = [];
  @track mandatedActivities = [];
  @track ifAppropriateActivities = [];
  @track optionalActivities = [];

  @track checkedBoxesIds = [];

  @wire(CurrentPageReference) getRecordIdFromURL(currentPageReference) {
      if (currentPageReference) {
        this.siteSurveyId = currentPageReference.attributes.recordId;
      }
  }
  
  get selectedIds() {
    return this.checkedBoxesIds.join(',');
  }
  
  selectAllCheckedOffActivities(event) {
    this.checkedBoxesIds = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input')].filter(element => element.checked).map(element => element.dataset.id);
    console.log('*** checkedBoxesIds: ' + this.checkedBoxesIds);
  }

  @wire(updateEventActivityCheckboxTracker, {siteSurveyId: '$siteSurveyId', checkedBoxesIds:'$checkedBoxesIds'}) wiredUpdateOfCheckboxTracker({ data, error }) {
    console.log('*** checkedBoxesIds: ' + this.checkedBoxesIds);
  }
  
  @wire(getEventActivityWrappers, {siteSurveyId:'$siteSurveyId'}) 
    wiredGetEventActivityWrappers({data, error}) {
      if (data) {
        console.log(data);
        this.activities = data;
        if(this.activities) {
          this.activities.forEach((activity) => {
            if(activity.type == "Mandated Activity") {
              this.mandatedActivities.push(activity);
            } else if(activity.type == "If Appropriate") {
              this.ifAppropriateActivities.push(activity); 
            } else if(activity.type == "Optional Activity") {
              this.optionalActivities.push(activity); 
            }
          })
        }
      } else if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
}
```

---

```
public with sharing class EventActivities_Ctrl {
  
  @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
  public static void updateEventActivityCheckboxTracker(String siteSurveyId, String activityIdsForTracker) {
    System.debug('*** siteSurveyId: ' + siteSurveyId);
    System.debug('*** activityIdsForTracker: ' + activityIdsForTracker);

    Site_Survey__c siteSurvey = [SELECT Id, Event_Activity_Checkbox_Tracker__c
                                 FROM Site_Survey__c 
                                 WHERE Id = :siteSurveyId];
    siteSurvey.Event_Activity_Checkbox_Tracker__c = activityIdsForTracker;
    update siteSurvey;

    System.debug('***Tracker from DB: ' + [SELECT Id, Event_Activity_Checkbox_Tracker__c
                                        FROM Site_Survey__c 
                                        WHERE Id = :siteSurveyId]);
  }

  @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
  public static List<EventActivityWrapper> getEventActivityWrappers(String siteSurveyId) {
    List<EventActivityWrapper> eventActivityWrappers = new List<EventActivityWrapper>();
    List<Event_Activity__c> eventActivities = [SELECT Id, Title__c, Type__c 
                                               FROM Event_Activity__c 
                                               ORDER BY Type__c ASC];
    Site_Survey__c siteSurvey = [SELECT Id, Event_Activity_Checkbox_Tracker__c
                                        FROM Site_Survey__c 
                                        WHERE Id = :siteSurveyId];

    for(Event_Activity__c eventActivity: eventActivities) {
      EventActivityWrapper eventActivityWrapper = new EventActivityWrapper(eventActivity.Id, 
                                                                           eventActivity.Title__c, 
                                                                           eventActivity.Type__c, 
                                                                           false);

      for(String activityIdFromTracker : siteSurvey.Event_Activity_Checkbox_Tracker__c.split(',')){
        if(activityIdFromTracker == eventActivity.Id){
          eventActivityWrapper.isChecked = true;
        }
      }
      eventActivityWrappers.add(eventActivityWrapper);
    }
    return eventActivityWrappers;
  }

  public class EventActivityWrapper{
        
    @AuraEnabled
    public Id activityId{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String title{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String type{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public Boolean isChecked{get;set;}

    public EventActivityWrapper(String activityId, String title, String type, Boolean isChecked) {
      this.activityId = activityId;
      this.title = title;
      this.type = type;
      this.isChecked = isChecked;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query the elements, filter by the checkbox, and then grab the data you want. This is pretty trivial:

```
this.checkedBoxesIds = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input')]
  .filter(element => element.checked)
  .map(element => element.dataset.id);
```

Where `[...iterable]` copies an array or array-like element into a proper Array, `Array.filter` checks the condition and returns only the matching elements, and `Array.map` translates an array into another array (by "mapping" the value).

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox! See Response to SFDC Fox in original message. Why is "*** checkedBoxesIds:" null in the Console? Also, I unchecked a single box. Why does "*** checkedBoxesIds:" print twice?

Comment: @RyanMcNeely change your onclick to an onchange

Comment: @sfdcfox why does checkedBoxesIds return null? also, I'm not clear on how element.dataset.id can grab onto the id from data-id attribute. When I tried element.dataset.data-id I got an error.

Comment: @RyanMcNeely See [my demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/rrzSynl7fAeKC6jYBlCR/src/app.css). It works fine for me.

Comment: @digglemister onclick works just fine. See demo (above).

Comment: @sfdcfox This is close, but you changed mandatedActivities and ifAppropriateActivities, and my other function is populating those with data from a Apex Wrapper Class. In my original message above, I gave code snippets to simplify, but I see it makes more sense to give you all the code. Please see updated original message. The plan was to update the DB via updateEventActivityCheckboxTracker. That said, if this is not the best way let me know.

Comment: @sfdcfox Also, I prefer the DB gets updated everytime 1 of 30 activities is checked or unchecked by the user; but if you know that won't work, I can do a Save button instead.

Comment: @RyanMcNeely Should be be possible. Let me review your code, I'll get back with you shortly.

Comment: @RyanMcNeely You can't update records when cacheable=true. Do not use a `@wire` method to update records. You need to call the update method [imperatively](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_call_imperative). I don't have a problem with onclick saving, that's my preferred method of updates in this kind of situation, but you do need imperative function calls.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. Worked like a charm. My Apex wrapper was passing "activityId", not "Id". That's why I was getting undefined in the console. And I converted an imperative method for update as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The final code works like a charm. When user clicks Save, it gets all IDs, sends all Ids to Apex as a String[]. In apex, updates a field with that string of Ids. So when the page is reloaded, all prior checkboxes are still checked.

---

```
    <template>
  <lightning-card>
  <h3 slot="title">
      <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:connected_apps" size="small"></lightning-icon>
      Activities
  </h3>
  <div class="slds-m-left_medium slds-m-right_medium slds-text-medium">
    Remember to click Save after checking off activities. Once all Mandated Activities 
    have been checked off, you may Submit to your manager.
  </div>

  <div slot="footer">
    <lightning-button label="Save" onclick={selectAllCheckedOffActivities} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
    <lightning-button label="Submit" title="Non-primary action" class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
  </div>


    <div class="slds-m-left_medium slds-m-top_medium slds-m-bottom_medium">
      <div class="slds-text-heading_medium">Mandated Activities</div>
      <template for:each={mandatedActivities} for:item="activity">
          <span key={activity.activityId}>
            <div class="slds-col">
                <lightning-input type="checkbox" data-id={activity.activityId} data-type={activity.type} label={activity.title} checked={activity.isChecked}></lightning-input>
            </div>
          </span>
      </template>
      <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-m-top_medium">If Appropriate</div>
      <template for:each={ifAppropriateActivities} for:item="activity">
        <span key={activity.activityId}>
          <div class="slds-col">
              <lightning-input type="checkbox" data-id={activity.activityId} label={activity.title} checked={activity.isChecked}></lightning-input>
          </div>
        </span>
      </template>
      <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-m-top_medium">Optional Activities</div>
      <template for:each={optionalActivities} for:item="activity">
        <span key={activity.activityId}>
          <div class="slds-col">
              <lightning-input type="checkbox" data-id={activity.activityId} label={activity.title} checked={activity.isChecked}></lightning-input>
          </div>
        </span>
      </template>
    </div>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

---

```
    import {LightningElement, wire, track} from 'lwc';
import {CurrentPageReference} from 'lightning/navigation';
import getEventActivityWrappers from '@salesforce/apex/EventActivities_Ctrl.getEventActivityWrappers';
import updateEventActivityCheckboxTracker from '@salesforce/apex/EventActivities_Ctrl.updateEventActivityCheckboxTracker';

export default class EventActivityChecklist extends LightningElement {

  @track currentPageReference = null;
  @track siteSurveyId = '';
  @track activityIdsForTracker = [];

  @track activities = [];
  @track mandatedActivities = [];
  @track ifAppropriateActivities = [];
  @track optionalActivities = [];


  @wire(CurrentPageReference) getRecordIdFromURL(currentPageReference) {
      if (currentPageReference) {
        this.siteSurveyId = currentPageReference.attributes.recordId;
      }
  }
  
  selectAllCheckedOffActivities(event) {
    this.activityIdsForTracker = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input')].filter(element => element.checked).map(element => element.dataset.id);
    console.log('*** activityIdsForTracker: ' + this.activityIdsForTracker);
    
    updateEventActivityCheckboxTracker(
      {siteSurveyId: this.siteSurveyId, activityIdsForTracker: this.activityIdsForTracker});
  }


  @wire(getEventActivityWrappers, {siteSurveyId:'$siteSurveyId'}) 
    wiredGetEventActivityWrappers({data, error}) {
      if(data) {
        console.log(data);
        this.activities = data;
        if(this.activities) {
          this.activities.forEach((activity) => {
            if(activity.type == "Mandated Activity") {
              this.mandatedActivities.push(activity);
            } else if(activity.type == "If Appropriate") {
              this.ifAppropriateActivities.push(activity); 
            } else if(activity.type == "Optional Activity") {
              this.optionalActivities.push(activity); 
            }
          })
        }
      } else if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
}
```

---

```
public with sharing class EventActivities_Ctrl {
  
  @AuraEnabled
  public static void updateEventActivityCheckboxTracker(String siteSurveyId, String[] activityIdsForTracker) {
    System.debug('*** siteSurveyId: ' + siteSurveyId);
    System.debug('*** activityIdsForTracker: ' + activityIdsForTracker);
    
    Site_Survey__c siteSurvey = [SELECT Id, Event_Activity_Checkbox_Tracker__c
                                 FROM Site_Survey__c 
                                 WHERE Id = :siteSurveyId];

    siteSurvey.Event_Activity_Checkbox_Tracker__c = 
      activityIdsForTracker.toString().remove('(').remove(')').remove(' ');

    update siteSurvey;
  }

  @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
  public static List<EventActivityWrapper> getEventActivityWrappers(String siteSurveyId) {
    List<EventActivityWrapper> eventActivityWrappers = new List<EventActivityWrapper>();
    List<Event_Activity__c> eventActivities = [SELECT Id, Title__c, Type__c 
                                               FROM Event_Activity__c 
                                               ORDER BY Type__c ASC];

    Site_Survey__c siteSurvey = [SELECT Id, Event_Activity_Checkbox_Tracker__c
                                 FROM Site_Survey__c 
                                 WHERE Id = :siteSurveyId];

    for(Event_Activity__c eventActivity: eventActivities) {
      EventActivityWrapper eventActivityWrapper = new EventActivityWrapper(eventActivity.Id, 
                                                                           eventActivity.Title__c, 
                                                                           eventActivity.Type__c, 
                                                                           false);
      if(siteSurvey.Event_Activity_Checkbox_Tracker__c != null){
        for(String activityIdFromTracker : siteSurvey.Event_Activity_Checkbox_Tracker__c.split(',')){
          if(activityIdFromTracker == eventActivity.Id){
            eventActivityWrapper.isChecked = true;
          }
        }
      }
      eventActivityWrappers.add(eventActivityWrapper);
    }
    return eventActivityWrappers;
  }

  public class EventActivityWrapper{
        
    @AuraEnabled
    public Id activityId{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String title{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String type{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public Boolean isChecked{get;set;}

    public EventActivityWrapper(String activityId, String title, String type, Boolean isChecked) {
      this.activityId = activityId;
      this.title = title;
      this.type = type;
      this.isChecked = isChecked;
    }
  }
}
```

---